# Estimating two break points in a broken stick model with random effects in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, piecewise-linear

Five months ago, jbowman posted a very useful answer to estimate the break point in a broken stick model with random effects in R. I never use "computing" like `ifelse` and I would like to estimate two break points. I should write two other functions like `b1` and `b2` but I don't know how. Can someone please tell me how to do that in R? Thanks!

jbowman's code:

```
library(lme4)
str(sleepstudy)

#Basis functions
bp = 4
b1 <- function(x, bp) ifelse(x < bp, bp - x, 0)
b2 <- function(x, bp) ifelse(x < bp, 0, x - bp)

#Wrapper for Mixed effects model with variable break point
foo <- function(bp)
{
  mod <- lmer(Reaction ~ b1(Days, bp) + b2(Days, bp) + (b1(Days, bp) + b2(Days, bp) | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
  deviance(mod)
}

search.range <- c(min(sleepstudy$Days)+0.5,max(sleepstudy$Days)-0.5)
foo.opt <- optimize(foo, interval = search.range)
bp <- foo.opt$minimum
bp
[1] 6.071932
mod <- lmer(Reaction ~ b1(Days, bp) + b2(Days, bp) + (b1(Days, bp) + b2(Days, bp) | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
```

Comment: Are you interested in having the slopes be continuous at the breakpoints or not?

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to work this out as well (**though not with random effects**), and I can only get a little further along. I'd be happy if @jbowman could take a look.

A model that allows for a double break (i.e. with breaks at $k_1$ and $k_2$ with $k_2 \gt k_1$) with slopes that are continuous is

$ Y = \beta_0 +\beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_3 + \epsilon $

where

$$
X_1 = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  X & if\ X \leq k_1\\
  k_1 & if\ X \gt k_1\\
\end{array} \right.
$$

$$
X_2 = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  0 & if\ X \leq k_1\\
  X-k_1 & if\ k_1 \leq X \leq k_2\\
  k_2-k_1  & if\ X \gt k_2\\
\end{array} \right.
$$

$$
X_3 = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  0 & if\ X \leq k_2\\
  X & if\ X \gt k_2\\
\end{array} \right.
$$

To convert this to R code, I think you can do this:

```
X1 <- function(x, k1) ifelse(x<=k1, x, k1)
X2 <- function(x, k1, k2) ifelse(x<=k1, 0, ifelse(x<=k2, x-k1, k2-k1))
X3 <- function(x, k2) ifelse(x<=k2, 0, x)
```

And then for breakpoints bp1 and bp2

```
out.lm <- lm(y ~ X1(x, bp1) + X2(x, bp1, bp2) + X3(x, bp2), data=yourdata)
Y <- out.lm$coef[1] + out.lm$coef[2]*X1(x, bp1) + out.lm$coef[3]*X2(x, bp1, bp2) + out.lm$coef[4]*X3(x, bp2)
```

Sadly, when i apply this to my own problem it produces rubbish :(  I'm no R programmer, hopefully someone with a bit more knowledge can help?

Ideally it'd be great to have a generic function to handle $n$ breakpoints.

Comment: A special note to get @jbowman 's attention as I can't add a comment to the question (too little rep).

Comment: Sorry, been awfully busy over the last few months, and I'll take a look at this over the next few days (whether or not you're interested any more!)

Comment: Yes indeed @jbowman, still interested!

Answer (score 2):

Section 9.3 of this [R code](http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/mi/FIMDmaterials/src/fimd9.r.txt) calculates random effect estimates for a broken stick model with multiple fixed break points.