# Estimating break point in a broken stick / piecewise linear model for one variable while including other as model terms

Tags: r, change-point, threshold, piecewise-linear

I am interested in estimating a break point in response to one explanatory variable, while also including other variables as terms in the linear model. One reason to include additional terms is to account for spatial dependency/autocorrelation. The following code was adapted from code provided by @jbowman [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/), and also referred to [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29327/).  It finds the break point for the model `lm(Rare25~epi.i)`.  What I would like to do is find a break point for `Rare25` at a value of `epi.i`, while including the variable `l.dist.mrc` in a model such as `lm(Rare25 ~ epi.i + l.dist.mrc)`.

**Data:**

```
epi.i<-c(7, 8, 9, 10, 8.01, 6, 7.01, 5.999, 4.003, 12, 2.01, 7.02, 10.01, 8.2, 5.9, 3.9, 6.999, 4.0001, 3.99, 6.001, 8.001, 5.99, 7.9, 6.99, 3.98)
Rare25<-c(4.471429, 4.551474, 4.204894, 4.456710, 3.504348, 4.175824, 4.298193, 4.406838, 3.058707, 4.451128, 1.000000, 4.327893, 3.580541, 4.082432, 3.630869, 4.352130, 3.919075, 3.795205, 3.380952, 2.993347, 3.775886, 3.766723, 3.852396, 3.923977, 4.308840)
l.dist.mrc<-c(2.7839, 2.7839, 2.7839, 3.0232, 3.0232, 2.5051, 2.5051, 2.7041, 2.9965, 3.0773, 3.4457, 3.1202, 3.1936, 3.4362, 3.3718, 2.7641, 2.7641, 3.7904, 3.4457, 3.7904, 3.1202, 2.5302, 2.5302 ,3.1242, 3.1241)
```

**Code:**

```
#Basis functions
bp = 4
b1 <- function(x, bp) ifelse(x < bp, bp - x, 0)
b2 <- function(x, bp) ifelse(x < bp, 0, x - bp)

#Wrapper
foo <- function(bp)
{
mod <- lm(Rare25 ~ b1(epi.i, bp) + b2(epi.i, bp))
deviance(mod)
}

search.range <- c(min(epi.i),max(epi.i))
foo.opt <- optimize(foo, interval = search.range)
bp <- foo.opt$minimum
bp

# confidence interval
foo.root <- function(bp, tgt)
{
foo(bp) - tgt
}
tgt <- foo.opt$objective + qchisq(0.95,1)

lb95 <- uniroot(foo.root, lower=(search.range[1]), upper=bp, tgt=tgt)
ub95 <- uniroot(foo.root, lower=bp, upper=search.range[2], tgt=tgt)
lb95$root
ub95$root
```

Comment: You can alter the first line of the `foo` function to:  `mod <- lm(Rare25 ~ b1(epi.i, bp) + b2(epi.i, bp) + l.dist.mrc)' for a not-very-generalizable solution.